# What is the minimal safe level of HTML escaping?

Tags: html, escaping

Assume I have some arbitrary text which we will call TEXT. If I replace all instances of `<` with `&lt;`, and all instances of `&` with `&amp;`, and substitute TEXT into an HTML document like so:

```
<div>TEXT</div>
```

Then have I done my duty as far as escaping special characters goes?

Answer (score 2):

Pretty much, yeah.

Escaping quotes can be useful as well, if there's a chance it might end up in an attribute string.

Comment: No, TEXT in my case will only ever be put in a text node.